# Merge cells with poi for powerpoint(xslf) error

Tags: java, apache-poi, powerpoint

```
private static void createTable(XSLFSlide slide) {
    XSLFTable table = slide.createTable();//创建3行13列的表格
    table.setAnchor(new Rectangle2D.Double(10, 50, 0, 0));
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        //新建行
        XSLFTableRow tableRow = table.addRow();
        for (int j = 0; j < 13; j++) {
            //新建单元格
            XSLFTableCell tableCell = tableRow.addCell();
            //设置单元格内容
            XSLFTextParagraph p = tableCell.addNewTextParagraph();
            XSLFTextRun run = p.addNewTextRun();
            //run.setText(String.valueOf(j));
            run.setText("test");
            //设置单元格样式
            tableCell.setFillColor(Color.getColor("0xdd7e6b"));
            p.setTextAlign(TextAlign.CENTER);
            tableCell.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.MIDDLE);
            tableCell.setBorderBottom(1);
            tableCell.setBorderLeft(1);
            tableCell.setBorderTop(1);
            tableCell.setBorderRight(1);
            tableCell.setBorderBottomColor(Color.BLACK);
            tableCell.setBorderLeftColor(Color.BLACK);
            tableCell.setBorderTopColor(Color.BLACK);
            tableCell.setBorderRightColor(Color.BLACK);
        }
        tableRow.setHeight(30);
    }
    //合并单元格
    table.mergeCells(0, 0, 4, 6);
    table.mergeCells(0, 0, 7, 9);
    table.mergeCells(0, 2, 0, 2);
    table.mergeCells(0, 2, 3, 3);
    table.mergeCells(1, 2, 4, 4);
    table.mergeCells(1, 2, 5, 5);
    table.mergeCells(1, 2, 6, 6);
    table.mergeCells(1, 2, 7, 7);
    table.mergeCells(1, 2, 8, 8);
    table.mergeCells(1, 2, 9, 9);
    table.mergeCells(0, 2, 10, 12);
}
```

I want to get a ppt file using the follow code, but this file is empty when I open with office 2007, and if I remove the last code `table.mergeCells(0, 2, 10, 12)` ,it's right.

So,can you tell me how to solve it?

Comment: Where the [XSLFTableCell](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xslf/usermodel/XSLFTableCell.html) `.setBorder...` methods are coming from? They are not from default `apache poi`.

Comment: I don't think so，this is my demo，and I use poi-3.9
https://github.com/minteliuwm/poi/tree/poi/ppt

Comment: Oh version 3.9. Just another fan of ancient software ;-). But I can reproduce this using `apache poi` version 3.16 too. So it seems to be a disadvantage of `PowerPoint 2007` since `PowerPoint 2016` is able to open that file correctly. But surely `PowerPoint`itself would never produce such a table having that amount of unnecessary cells in it. This table needs only 2 rows and 9 columns really and not 3 rows and 13 columns.

Comment: yeah,I hava found it too,and I can avoid it by create a table with 2 rows and 9 columns, but I still want to know why and how.